# my program is to generate a code for calculating 4 point fft

Tags: vhdl

I have written the code in three parts. The first part contains functions such as add, subtract and negate. The second part is the butterfly structure. The third part is  fft4.

I find some errors in butterfly part, please help to solve these.

The program is given below. In fft_pkg instead of multiplication by -j, I used negation function.

I avoided multiplication by 1 and -j and used addition and negate function.

```
-- Design Name: 
-- Module Name:    butterfly - Behavioral 
-- Project Name: 
-- Target Devices: 
-- Tool versions: 
-- Description: 
--
-- Dependencies: 
--
-- Revision: 
-- Revision 0.01 - File Created
-- Additional Comments: 
-------------------------------------------------------------
library ieee;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library work;
use work.fft_pkg.all;

entity butterfly is 
   port (
      s1,s2 : in  complex;
      stage : in  std_logic;            -- inputs
   -- w :     in  complex               -- phase factor
      g1,g2 : out complex               -- outputs
   );
end butterfly;

architecture Behavioral of butterfly is 

begin 

--butterfly equations.

    if ( stage ='0') then
        g1 <= add(s1,s2);
        g2 <= sub(s1,s2);
    elsif (stage ='1') then
        g1 <= add(s1,negate(s2));
        g2 <= sub(s1,negate(s2));
    end if;

end Behavioral;

--butterfly structure(in it instead of multiplication negate func is used)

library ieee;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
library work;
use work.fft_pkg.all;

entity butterfly is 
   port (
      s1,s2 : in  complex;
      stage : in  std_logic;           -- inputs
   -- w :     in  complex;             -- phase factor
      g1,g2 :out complex            -- outputs
   );
end butterfly;

architecture Behavioral of butterfly is 

begin 

--butterfly equations.

    if ( stage ='0') then
        g1 <= add(s1,s2);
        g2 <= sub(s1,s2);
    elsif (stage ='1') then
        g1 <= add(s1,negate(s2));
        g2 <= sub(s1,negate(s2));
    end if;
end Behavioral;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library work;
use work.fft_pkg.all;

entity fft4 is 
    port ( 
        s:     in  comp_array;
        y :    out comp_array
    );
  end fft4;

architecture rtl of fft4 is

    component butterfly is
        port (
            s1,s2 : in  complex;      -- inputs
         -- w :     in  complex;      -- phase factor
            g1,g2 : out complex       -- outputs
        );
   end component;

   signal g1,g2:  comp_array;  -- :=(others=>(0000,0000));
-- signal w:comp_array2 :=(("0000","0001"),("0000","1111"));

begin

 --first stage of butterfly

bf11 : butterfly port map(s(0),s(2),'0',g1(0),g1(1));
bf12 : butterfly port map(s(1),s(3),'0',g1(2),g1(3));

--second stage of butterfly's.

bf21 : butterfly port map(g1(0),g1(2),'0',g2(0),g2(2));
bf22 : butterfly port map(g1(1),g1(3),'1',g2(1),g2(3));
end rtl;
```

Errors are

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\RObin\fftfinal\butterfly.vhd" Line 36: Syntax error near "if".
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\RObin\fftfinal\butterfly.vhd" Line 39: Syntax error near "elsif".
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:\Users\RObin\fftfinal\butterfly.vhd" Line 42: Syntax error near "if".
>   ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - "C:\Users\RObin\fftfinal\butterfly.vhd" Line 31: Unit  ignored due to previous errors.

Comment: If test must be included in a process.
Instead, you can do:
g1 <= add(s1,s2) when stage ='0' else g1 <= add(s1,negate(s2));

The same for g2.

Comment: You haven't actually displayed all three parts of your code. Also the errors relate to the if statements in the architecture body.  If statements are sequential statements and belong in (in this case) a process statement.  There will likely be other things wrong,  once you fix your if statements. Supplement your question, don't replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the if statements into a process:

```
architecture behavioral of butterfly is 

begin 

--butterfly equations.
   process (s1, s2)
   begin
        if ( stage ='0') then
            g1 <= add(s1,s2);
            g2 <= sub(s1,s2);
        elsif (stage ='1') then
            g1 <= add(s1,negate(s2));
            g2 <= sub(s1,negate(s2));
        end if;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

It's not possible to verify your code without either package fft_pkg, or writing one, which would seem to require deciding what the type `complex` is.

Note that while Nicolas also commented that you could use concurrent conditional assignment statements, all concurrent statements have equivalent process statements or processes and block statements, which is how VHDL is both simulated and synthesized after elaboration.

You can also comment out or remove one of the two copies of entity butterfly and it's architecture Behavioral.  If you need two different representations with the same interface you can change the architecture name of successive different architectures.

By default the last one analyzed will be used. Analyzing the same named entity and architecture over again has the effect of replacing the first occurrence while still requiring both are valid VHDL.